# Undefined Variable Is Actually Defined?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on getting a simple registration/login form to work. I'm currently having issues accessing my connection to the database. I keep getting an "Undefined Variable".

Here is my code for my connect:

```
<?php

$hostName = 'localhost';
$userName = 'root';
$userPass = '';
$database = 'test';

$con = new mysqli($hostName, $userName, $userPass, $database);

if($con->connect_errno){
    printf("Connect failed...");
    exit();
}
```

By including this in my php file, shouldn't I be able to access $con? Or do I have to redefine my connection every time I access the file?

From my experience before I haven't had to redefine it, so I am kind of skeptical on doing that. Here is the function/s that are tripping it up.

```
<?php

include 'user-functions.php';
include 'connect.php';

function checkDuplicateEmail($email){
    $query = "SELECT `playerEmail` FROM `players` WHERE `playerEmail` = '$email'";

    $result = $con->query($query);

    if($result->num_rows > 1){
        addError("Duplicate email: " . $email);
        return True;
    }
    return False;
}

function checkDuplicateUserName($userName){
    $query = "SELECT `playerName` FROM `players` WHERE `playerName` = '$userName'";

    $result = $con->query($query);

    if($result->num_rows > 1){
        addError("Duplicate username: " . $userName);
        return True;
    }
    return False;
}

?>
```

Now, this is the only position that it's saying "Undefined Variable" for $con. Am I missing something?

These are the two errors from the webpage:

1. Undefined variable: con
2. Call to member function query() on a non-object.

Comment: You might previously have used a constant, which is available globally without having to use `global`. Constants are set using `define()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$con` is in the global scope and is not available to your functions. You need to pass it as a parameter for the code in your functions to have access to it:

```
function checkDuplicateEmail($email, $con){
    $query = "SELECT `playerEmail` FROM `players` WHERE `playerEmail` = '$email'";

    $result = $con->query($query);

    if($result->num_rows > 1){
        addError("Duplicate email: " . $email);
        return True;
    }
    return False;
}

$var = checkDuplicateEmail($email, $con);
```

You can also use the `global` keyword but that is bad practice so I won't recommend it here.

Comment: Thanks! It is weird, before I never had to pass the connection to each OR create a global. And it just worked, that's why I am confused. It may just be a hiccup in the code somewhere. I basically just went through and re-wrote things to clear up any chance of bugs or bypassing the registration.

Comment: @teepleb, it's worth _hinting_ this parameter too. So use `function checkDuplicateEmail($email, mysqli $con)`, so you can only pass a valid connection to it.

Comment: @teepleb if previously you were using the `mysql_*` functions, if you used mysql_query and didn't supply the connection parameter, it would look for the last open connection and just use that. Using the OOP method you need to get access to the object in order to query and inside of a function you don't have access without passing it in as a parameter as the answer suggests.

Answer (score 3):

This is a scoping issue. Either define `$con` as a global or pass it as an argument into each function that needs it.